# MPI One Sided: Exclusive Lock with MPI_Win_lock_all

Tags: c, locking, mpi

The MPI-3 Standard states that `MPI_Win_lock(...)` with lock type `MPI_LOCK_SHARED` must be a blocking (exclusive) lock if and only if the origin and target process are the same. `MPI_Win_lock_all` is the locking of all processes in the window with lock type `MPI_LOCK_SHARED`.

Does this imply that `MPI_Win_lock_all` creates also an exclusive lock from the origin to the origin itself?

Comment: Good question. Can you remind me what page of the spec you are citing?

Answer (score 1):

No.  `MPI_Win_lock_all` induces a shared lock at all processes associated with the window (technically, in the group associated with the window).

In any case, a shared lock and an exclusive lock are different.  Please do not conflate the possibility that shared lock acquisition will block on some remote state with an exclusive lock.